# QT no such slot

Tags: c++, qt

I've got such piece of code:

przystanki.h

```
#ifndef PRZYSTANKI_H
#define PRZYSTANKI_H
#include "component.h"
class Przystanki : public Component
{
public:
    Przystanki(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void deletePosition(QString);
public slots:
    void deleteListItem();
    void addListItem(QString label);
    void createListItem(QString label, DodajPrzystanek* elem);

};

#endif // PRZYSTANKI_H
```

component.h

```
#ifndef COMPONENT_H
#define COMPONENT_H
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include "dodajprzystanek.h"
class Component : public QGroupBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Component(QString name, QWidget *parent = 0);
    QListWidget* list;

};

#endif // COMPONENT_H
```

fragment which uses it:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent)
{
webView = new MyWebView(this);
mainlayout = new QGridLayout();
mainlayout->addWidget(webView, 0,0);
Przystanki *stop = new Przystanki(this);
mainlayout->addWidget(stop, 0, 1);
QHBoxLayout* bottom = new QHBoxLayout();
//bottom->addWidget(new QLabel("Linie"));
bottom->addWidget(new Component("Autobusy"));
bottom->addWidget(new Component("Linie"));
QHBoxLayout* hrightCorner = new QHBoxLayout();
QVBoxLayout* rightCorner = new QVBoxLayout();
rightCorner->addStretch(1);
rightCorner->addWidget(new QPushButton("Start", this));
//QLabel* label = new QLabel("Labelka");

//rightCorner->addWidget(label);
rightCorner->addStretch(1);
hrightCorner->addLayout(rightCorner);
mainlayout->addLayout(bottom, 1, 0);
mainlayout->addLayout(hrightCorner, 1, 1);
hrightCorner->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
this->setCentralWidget(new QWidget);
this->centralWidget()->setLayout(mainlayout);
connect(webView, SIGNAL(getMapPosition(QString)), stop, SLOT(addListItem(QString)));
connect(stop, SIGNAL(deletePosition(QString)), webView, SLOT(deleteMarker(QString)));


}
```

What I get is:

```
loaded the Generic plugin 
Object::connect: No such slot Component::addListItem(QString)
Object::connect: No such signal Component::deletePosition(QString)
```

It happend after I moved definitions of slots and signals from Component to it's derived class Przystanki. I've removed whole build directory, run clean, run qmake and build one more time and it didn't help. Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see here in this piece of code any relevant `connect` calls. Also, there should be filename and line, where does that connect occures.

Comment: I've editted the question. I removed a few first lines with no slot becouse in this case the slot was really missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class Przystanki is missing the Q_OBJECT macro. Add it, add przystanki.h to HEADERS in the .pro file (if not there yet) and rerun qmake.

Comment: I've tried to do so, but then I get linker errors, which I don't understand. The error is: undefined reference to `vtable for Przystanki'

Comment: @WojciechReszelewski, it means, that your *.moc doesn't link into. Probably you have some problem with your buildsystem.

Comment: I've removed whole build directory, clean, run qmake and build again and it worked. Thanks a lot.